# Explain the code? Can compare logical and double?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
f=imread('cameraman.tif');
f=im2bw(f);
[m,n]=size(f);
s1=zeros(m,2*n);
s1(1:end,1:2:end)=f(1:end,1:end);
```

Here is what i think the code does.
We are changing s1, by comparing and replacing its element with the elements of f. s1 is a 256x512 double matrix where as f is a 256x256 logical matrix. But i don't think that's correct because after seeing and matching both the matrix i saw that not all the elements were in that fashion.

Can please someone briefly explain what does this code actually do? And how actually it done?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines read an image from a file and convert it to a binary image (so that `f` is now a logical matrix.)

```
f=imread('cameraman.tif');
f=im2bw(f);
```

These lines create a new matrix `s1` which has the same number of rows as `f` but twice the number of columns.

```
[m,n]=size(f);
s1=zeros(m,2*n);
```

This line fills every other column of `s1` with the values of `f`. The result is that the odd-numbered columns (1,3,5....) in `s` will contain a copy of `f` and the even-numbered columns (2,4,6...) will be zero.

```
s1(1:end,1:2:end)=f(1:end,1:end);
```

Note that it's actually being a little verbose; you could get the same result by doing

```
s1(:,1:2:end) = f;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code has been explained well by other answer, so how about an example to give you a graphical illustration.

First, you should know by `im2bw`, the image is turned into black and white, meaning the image matrix is converted to 2D.

Input image:

[image]

Black and White image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

Note that the third image has been augmented with zeros in even-columns. DOUBLE FAT!

Zoom in at left upper corner:

[image]

Comment: You're Chinese. Catch you. :)

Comment: @herohuyongtao Undergrad in HKUST, nice to know you.

Comment: I upvoted, but I think this would be much better if all the images were 1/3 to 1/2 the size.

Comment: @Chris Agreed. Doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=imread('cameraman.tif');
```

loading file to f

```
 f=im2bw(f);
```

converting f to black and white f

```
[m,n]=size(f);
```

getting size od array (simple: image dimensions)

```
s1=zeros(m,2*n);
```

creating an array of zeros - dimension of new array is double (you can insert 2 cameraman.tif images inside s1 left and right because this is 2* columns )

```
s1(1:end,1:2:end)=f(1:end,1:end);
```

this line is a little tricky - it inserts image f into image s1 but every second line so it looks widen
you can see it yourself :)
just

```
imshow(s1);
```